# how to get text between 2 spaces in shell

Tags: shell-script

my text would be like this:

```
$Head: mxedt.tmple 233454.45673.1236786 2020/10/89 08:41:58 floojn nmat $
```

from above line, I need to grab only 233454.45673.1236786. and this value is not constant always, I need a way to get first number after mxedt.tmple

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Answer (score 1):

With [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) and regex in [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) mode:

```
grep -oP 'mxedt\.tmple\s+\K\S+'
```

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: the number is not constant always

Comment: thanks alot, got it.